# openpop example not working in VS2012 express C#

Tags: openpop

When I paste this code in

```
// Download the full message
                Message message = client.GetMessage(messageNumber);
```

the error is :
Error   3   'Message' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Forms.Message' and 'OpenPop.Mime.Message'   c:\users\mpho\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication26\WindowsFormsApplication26\Form1.cs    62  21  WindowsFormsApplication26

What must be done to solve this ?

D

Answer (score 0):

Use full namespace and it will fix the issue..

```
OpenPop.Mime.Message message = client.GetMessage(messageNumber);
```